# protractor/selenium "could not find chromedriver at" (on Windows)

Tags: windows, angularjs, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, protractor

I installed protractor following [this tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-getting-started-with-protractor) and when i use webdriver-manager update it says:

```
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.
```

thou when i try to run the protractor tests, it says:

```
C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\local.dp.js:42
            throw new Error('Could not find chromedriver at ' +
                  ^
    Error: Could not find chromedriver at C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe
        at LocalDriverProvider.addDefaultBinaryLocs_ (C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\local.dp.js:42:15)
        at LocalDriverProvider.setupEnv (C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\local.dp.js:59:8)
        at Runner.run (C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:308:31)
        at process.<anonymous> (C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runFromLauncher.js:32:14)
        at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
        at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:345:11)
    [launcher] Runner Process Exited With Error Code: 8
```

I checked the *local.dp.js* and saw that it tried to load the chromedriver from *..\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver* but there only was an empty zip file called *chromedriver_2.9*.

So i downloaded the chromedriver manually and copied it to this location, producing a new error:

```
C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1549
      throw error;
            ^
Error: Server exited with 1
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at ChildProcess.onServerExit (C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:193:11)
    at ChildProcess.g (events.js:180:16)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
[launcher] Runner Process Exited With Error Code: 8
```

Anyone any Ideas?

Comment: i tried downloading chromedriver and putting it to the ..\node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver.exe directly and it produced a new error

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are behind a proxy then try setting proxy first and then run webdriver update:

```
npm config set proxy http://<proxy.com>:port

webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: Delete 0 bytes files from /selenium folder first

Comment: Thanks. That was why the webdriver-manager update did not work.

Comment: you should also set the proxy for webdriver-manager as described [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/537)

Answer (score 67):

I was facing this error too and by the time I read the tutorial, it did not cover how to install protractor and the webdriver as local dependencies to your project (which are located in ./node_modules).

If this is what you prefer (probably because you might want to use grunt-protractor-runner and run your test later in a continuous build manner as I neede) instead of installing it globally, this solution worked for me:

1. Install protractor:

`npm install protractor --save-dev`

2. Install selenium and the webdrivers with the webdriver-manager by running:

`./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`

After calling this command have a look at `./node_modules/protractor` and it subfolders to verify it. A folder called `selenium` with the `chromedriver` in should be available in it.

Note that as protractor was not installed as "global", calling it from the command line will result in a "commnad not found" error. 
You can run it instead with this command:
`./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor`

Additionaly, it might be a good idea to add a script definition to your package.json, so that next time you install all your dependencies from zero, npm setup the webdrivers automaticaly. For that add this to your package.json file:

 `"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
  }`

Hope this helps you further...

Comment: This answer actually solves the problem in a sane way. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for Windows 8.1 Enterprise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: for me, it was needed just to run: `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`.

awesome. thank you

Comment: I have Chrome browser version 80 and I executed the **webdriver-manager update** but it thrown the error like *Could not find chromedriver at* I checked the node_modules/Web-driver Manager/Selenium but it does not have the relevant chrome driver version for browser version 80. Instead it had the chrome driver like 78,79 only

Answer (score 24):

I followed that tutorial and had the same problem. The issue here was that you need to specify  the path to your selenium jar and chrome driver exe in your protractor config file. Mine was installed globally in AppData folder so this is what mine ***protractor.confg.js*** file looks like:

```
exports.config = {

specs: [
    'test/e2e/**/*.js'
],

chromeDriver: 'C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe',

seleniumServerJar: 'C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar',

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/'

};
```

That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Also important to note I'm running protractor through Grunt, which runs with a connect task on port 9000. Hence the reason I've specified 9000 in my config.

Comment: chromeDriver: 'C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe', This part alone did it for me. I had previously installed (npm install -g protractor) globally and I wasn't able to run a gulp task from a specific directory. Thank you Chester.

Comment: It's a bit risky to add absolute paths when you are working with a team. For me the answer by @stitakis (running a webdriver-manager update) did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

Jeez, so many answers...

On the Mac, this worked for me:

```
$ npm install chromedriver
$ ln -sf ~/angular-phonecat/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe
```

There's GOT to be a better way of fixing it but at least this let me move on.

Comment: Adding this to package.json will allow `npm install` to take care of it: `"postinstall": "echo -n $NODE_ENV | grep -v 'production' && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update || echo 'will NOT run webdriver install or update in production only'"`

Comment: The zip file was always corrupted when I downloaded it. I'm not behind a proxy, so I'm not sure the problem. But I was able to get it to work with this process though running "npm run protractor" downloads chromedriver and places the executable in node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/, so I linked it to there instead of the bin/ directory.  When I did npm install chromedriver it just put a 398-byte stub in the bin/ directory.

Answer (score 7):

After looking around for a while, I noticed that the `package.json` file included in [the angular phonecat repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat) defines a `update-webdriver` task.

Running that task (with `npm run update-webdriver`) fixed protractor for me.

Answer (score 4):

The Chrome driver can exist in any location, but the protractor runner seems to expect it to be in the location where it would exist if you installed it through "webdriver-manager". Thus, it can be installed with "npm install chromedriver", which will place it in a different location, such as:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver

In this case, the config file will need to be set to look in this location, but there is likelt a simpler solution...

If webdriver-manager fails to download either the chromedriver or selenium-standalone, there will be 0-byte files in the default location, which will cause this error. Unfortunately, this can happen with proxy related issues. Once the corrupt files are there, the update check process thinks everything is up-to-date, but it's not.

Also, the proxy configuration for webdriver-manager is different than npm. For webdriver-manager, the syntax to do an update would be:

```
sudo webdriver-manager update --proxy=http://<your proxy server>/
```

Clearing out the 0-byte files and re-running this update command should replace the files with their correct data. The location on my machine for these files is:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium
```

Comment: Starting with protractor 1.0.x the default npm environment settings are used

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the due to damaged chromedriver zip file.

I have done following things to resolve this problem.

1. Downloaded chromedriver zip from [ChromeDriver Download Page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
2. Extracted that zip file at **"node_modules\protractor\selenium\"** (i.e. Copied "chromedriver.exe" to this location)

Then it started working as expected. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered similar issue when I followed angular's tutorial:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

and checked out the code accordingly:

```
git checkout -f step-3
```

Within angular-phonecat/package.json devDependencies, the protractor version is "~1.0.0", which caused npm always download a corrupted file:

angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.10.zip

Because the above zip file can't be opened properly, so below error exists:

/Users/karlli/dev/projects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/adm-zip/zipFile.js:66
            throw Utils.Errors.INVALID_FORMAT;
                              ^
Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found

There are 2 solutions:

1. symbol link the correct one instead

`ln -sf ~/dev/projects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe`

Thanks @bronson :-)

2. upgrade protractor's dependency version
   After several tests, I found the minimal workable version is 1.1.0.

angular-phonecat/package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^0.12.16",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
    "protractor": "~1.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "tmp": "0.0.23",
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

On windows, I was having trouble with a project that ran fine on my mac. The command that finally got it done for me was:

```
node node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager update
```

Answer (score 1):

If on Windows, you may need to set an `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable. Try these steps in your command prompt, assuming your proxy server is `http://proxy.you.com:8080`.

1. `SETX HTTP_PROXY http://proxy.you.com:8080` *(It should return SUCCESS: Specified value was saved. You can also do this in System Properties...Advanced...Environment Variables)*
2. Close your command prompt window and reopen. (*This ensures your new environment variable will be used in your session*.)
3. Now run your command: `webdriver-manager update`

Comment: The proxy is already defined using the `--proxy=http://<your proxy server>/` Parameter as defined in the Answer given by @CleverCoder. Thanks thou.

Answer (score 1):

On mac osx, change the version in package.json for protractor to "*", remove node_modules, and install again.

Answer (score 0):

The standalone selenium file was corrupt so i had to overwrite it, copying it into the folder directly.

```
C:/Users/****/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/
```

Also i had to rename the chromedriver so it is actually called "chromedriver" and not "chromedriver.exe".

```
C:/Users/****/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver
```

This partially happened because i did not set the proxy in webdriver. You can see the Solution for this in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22223463/532495).

Answer (score 0):

For me the `npm install` and `npm run update-webdriver` commands just kept downloading the corrupt `Chromedriver_x.xx.zip` file. So I tried running `webdriver-manager update`, and it worked.

Answer (score -3):

Just add the "preprotractor":" npm install chromedriver"   to your package.json

That will down load the latest one all the time.