# Error: Could not find chromedriver while following angularjs official tutorial

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, npm

At first I have to say this is my first touch with angularjs and node.js so this will be probably a stupid issue, but I want to learn to work with angularjs so I followed this tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial and everything went as expected, until I got to **Running End to End Tests** part.

When I run this command:

```
npm run update-webdriver
```

it says:

```
selenium standalone is up to date. 
chromedriver is up to date.
```

Then I turn on the local server:

```
npm start
```

And while its running I run tests:

```
npm run protractor
```

which in my terminal results into:
o

> Using ChromeDriver directly...
>
> [launcher] Error: Could not find chromedriver at
>   /home/qw/www/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe

Th file chromedriver.exe really doesnt exists (there is chromedriver_2.10.zip), and I really dont think an .exe file should be there, considering Im using ubuntu 14.04 (this tutorial shoul be for angular version is 1.4.0).

Is this a tuto for some windows version?

Could anyone help me (the way a beginner could understand :) )?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use the `webdriver-manager` from inside the `protractor` package:

```
node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: For those running NPM, [you can also run this from a "postinstall" script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29856384/2831961)

Comment: if you are having issues with SSL you can ignore SSL by running the above command but adding --ignore_ssl

Answer (score 10):

I was following the tutorial on [AngularJS step 3](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03) and had the same issue, but it was caused by missing chromedriver file. I solved it by the following steps:

1. Go to folder angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\selenium to see if you have the following two files:

   - chromedriver.exe
   - selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar
2. If not, download the chromedriver from here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
   and the selenium from here:
   http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
3. Then put the downloaded files to the `angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\selenium` folder
4. In the command window, enter `npm start` to startup the app and in the second command window, enter `npm run protractor` to run the end to end test with protractor.

Then you will see the lovely Chrome window come up and run the tests.